# JPA - DB maintanence causes deadlock / hang on recovery?

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa

Im relatively new to JPA and have "inherited" this code, but I have an issue with what appears to be a deadlock / hang. This only occurs when our database becomes unavailable for a certain amount of time (maintanence). There is potentially 10 seperate threads / processors and essentially one hits a db exception which it loops and tries to recover from and the others appear to hang for days

I have searched but I can't find what Im looking for so apologies if this is a repeat.

isCommunicationFailure() reports a db error and restarts the process

**Thread #1** 
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Broken pipeError Code: 17002  at com.SomeClass.isCommunicationFailure

**Thread #2** 
INFO: Persisting...
Feb 14, 2015 7:55:23 PM com.SomeClass.transitionUncachedToState
INFO: About to commit job state....
Feb 15, 2015 2:04:35 PM com.SomeClass.JPAJobStore  <--- **This is where we restart the process as its not moved.**

Would I need to set certain objects OPTIMISTIC? or would a timeout on locks? Or is there some other fundimental way of dealing with it?

I'm using Oracle DB back end. persistence.xml below too (I've manually changed some classnames for this question to be generic).

Thanks in advance ... :)

```
public boolean transitionUncachedToState(Job job, String zId)
throws RAAException
{
    boolean                                 result = false;
    String                                  jobReqId = job.getJobRequestId();
    Query                                   query;
    Job              jpaJob;        
    long starttime, stoptime;
    starttime = DateUtil.getCurrentUtcTime();
    try {
        query = em.createNamedQuery("getUnzippedJobUsingJobReqId");
    query.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 30000);
        query.setParameter("jobReqId", jobReqId);
        jpaJob = (Job)query.getSingleResult();
        em.refresh(jpaJob);
        stoptime = DateUtil.getCurrentUtcTime();
        logger.info("get jpaJob="+jpaJob.toString().substring(0, 512)
            + ", time in miliseconds " + (stoptime-starttime));
        starttime = stoptime;
    } 
    catch(NoResultException ex) 
    {
        logger.info("job " + jobReqId + " can not be locked.");
        return result;
    }

    //jpaReportCacheState = jpaJob.getJobDetails().getReportCacheState();
    JobDetails jpaJobDetails = jpaJob.getJobDetails();
    em.refresh(jpaJobDetails);
    ProcessingState jpaState = jpaJobDetails.getProcessingState();
    em.refresh(jpaState);
    logger.info("Job.Z_STATE_UNPROCESSED="
        + Job.Z_STATE_UNPROCESSED
        + ", jpaState.getState()="+jpaState.getState());
    if(Job.Z_STATE_UNPROCESSED.equals(jpaState.getState()))
    {
                    // Set Job's report cache state to CACHING
        job.setStartTime(DateUtil.getCurrentUtcTime());
        job.setState(Job.Z_STATE_ZIPPING);
        job.setId(zId);
        job.setProcessingAttempts(job.getProcessingAttempts() + 1);
         try {
            logger.info(job.getId());
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            jpaState.setState(job.getState());
            jpaState.setStartProcessingTime(new Date(job.getStartTime()));
            jpaJob.setId(job.getId());
            logger.info("Persisting...");

    em.persist(jpaState);
            em.persist(jpaJob);
    logger.info("About to commit job state....");
            em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.clear();
            stoptime = DateUtil.getCurrentUtcTime(); 
            logger.info("Successful lock on job " + jobReqId
                    + ", JPA update time in miliseconds " + (stoptime-starttime));
            result = true;
        } 
        catch(Exception ex) {
            if(isCommunicationFailure(ex)) {
                result = transitionUncachedToState(job, zId);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}



   <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence persistence_1_0.xsd"
         version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>
       oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
    </provider>

    <class>com.SomeClass.Job</class>


    <properties>
        <property name  ="toplink.target-database" value="Oracle"/>

        <property name="user" value="somthing"/>
        <property name="password" value="somthing123"/>    

        <property name="toplink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/>
        <property name="toplink.logging.exceptions" value="true"/>

        <!--<property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>-->
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@someurl"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="pass"/>

        <property name="toplink.jdbc.bind-parameters" value="true"/>
        <property name="toplink.cache.size.default" value="5000"/>
        <property name="toplink.cache.shared.ContainerEntry" value="false"/>
        <property name="toplink.cache.shared.Hosts" value="false"/>
        <property name="toplink.cache.shared.default" value="true"/>
        <property name="toplink.weaving" value="true"/>


        <property name="toplink.jdbc.read-connections.max" value="1"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.read-connections.min" value="1"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.write-connections.max" value="1"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.write-connections.min" value="1"/>

        <property name="toplink.cache.type.Order" value="Weak"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: deadlock / hang ? It's a big difference. Oracle detects deadlocks at "realtime", and report an error to the application instantly. Each deadlock occurence also generates detailed tracefile on DB server. You really should check, what's really going on inside the database.

Comment: Are you using a connection pool?

Comment: Not a connection pool on this each process is on a different box with one connection each (There's a web app that uses connection pools to the same db).. I will try and get the logs (db)